# On the Absolute Value of the Chromatic Polynomial

Tags: graph-theory, polynomials

I am having trouble solving problem 12.1 of Chromatic Polynomials and Chromaticity of Graphs by Dong, Koh and Teo. It is as follows:

Let $G$ be any connected graph of order $n.$ Prove that $|P(G,\lambda)|\geq\lambda(1-\lambda)^{n-1}$ for all real $\lambda\in (0,1).$

In the chapter text, it seems to suggest using induction. If G has $n$ vertices and $m$ edges, I am trying to induct on $n+m.$

The base case is of $n=1,m=0$ is trivial, since $G\cong K_1$ and the chromatic polynomials are equal.

I then assume that the result is true for any graph of order $n'$ and size $m'$ with $n'+m' < n+m.$ I choose an edge $e$ in $G.$ Then, by the deletion-contraction theorem, we know that $P(G,\lambda) = P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G\cdot e,\lambda).$ Because both of these graphs are "smaller" than $G,$ we can then use the induction hypothesis on them. This much is obvious, but I get stuck here: 
$$\begin{align*}|P(G,\lambda)| &= |P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G\cdot e,\lambda)|  \\
&\geq |P(G-e,\lambda)| - |P(G\cdot e,\lambda)| \\
&\geq \lambda(1-\lambda)^{n-1} - |P(G\cdot e,\lambda)|\end{align*}$$
The last inequality holds because $P(G-e,\lambda)$ has the same number of vertices as $G.$ The problem is that I recognise that this does not imply the desired inequality.

Comment: After a night's sleep and a small break, I noticed that I had missed what should have been a common trick in analysis. Here we go:
$$\begin{align}
|P(G,\lambda)| &= |P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G\cdot e,\lambda)| \\
&= |P(G-e,\lambda) + P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G\cdot e,\lambda)| \\
&\geq |P(G-e,\lambda) + P(G-e,\lambda)| - |P(G-e,\lambda) - P(G\cdot e,\lambda)| \\
&\geq |P(G-e,\lambda) + P(G-e,\lambda)| - |P(G,\lambda)|
\end{align}$$
This implies that $$2|P(G,\lambda)| \geq 2|P(G-e,\lambda)|$$ and the result follows easily.